# firebug: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: jquery

sorry for my bad english
my code work with jquery 1.4.2 but not work with 1.7.1
I am receiving "missing ) after argument list" error in firebug with the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').html($('#content').html().replace(/#([a-zA-Z1-9]{1,})/gi,'<a href="<?php echo $this->webroot ?>instagrams/index/$1" class="tag_replace">#$1</a>'));
});
```

my generated code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').html($('#content').html().replace(/#([a-zA-Z1-9]{1,})/gi,'<a href="/instagram/instagrams/index/$1" class="tag_replace">#$1</a>'));
});
```

browser error code :
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]

...agram/instagrams/index/content" class="tag_replace">#content").append(html)

jquery....min.js (line 11, col 63)

Comment: Paste your generated code here, not the raw code with the PHP.

Comment: if you have a JS syntax error (which is what the error message is telling you), then it wouldn't work in any version of jquery. If it used to work but doesn't now, then something else must have changed as well. But as @j08691 says, you'll need to show us the code that the browser sees, not the PHP code.

Comment: OMG no, there's _never_ a good reason to dynamically write Javascript using PHP code...

Comment: is `#content` an `<a>` element?

Comment: @Alnitak : #content is like #container

Comment: @user1641998 so it's just a `<div>`, with lots of child elements?

Comment: @Alnitak: yes, there is a lot

Comment: @user1641998 your client side code would be a lot easier if the server side PHP enclosed each `#foo` ID in a `<span class="picture">` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* write JS code dynamically using PHP, put the relevant variable on a line of its own so you can separate out problems with that from problems with your JS code.

You can also take advantage of the function parameter version of `.html()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').html(function(index, old) {
        var root = "<?php echo $this->webroot ?>";
        var match = /#([a-zA-Z1-9]{1,})/gi;

        return old.replace(match, '<a href="' + root + 'instagram/instagrams/index/$1" class="tag_replace">#$1</a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]  

$('<a ref="/instagram//instagram/instagrams/index/loading" class="tag_replace">#...